# MySQL Group by - AWS capacity

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, group-by, rds

I have situation where in i have table with 35,00,00,000 records in a mysql on Amazon EC2 instance (MYISAM table) which has 5 columns. I need to do  group by function for all the columns for a specific task

This is how I fire the query select a,b,c,d,sum(f) as e from table a group by a,b,c,d where in a and b are integer columns and c,d are string columns. I  have indexed these columns as well.I have 18GB of space available.

But when I looked at the query using explain

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------  ----+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows       | Extra                           |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------ ----+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | TABLE A  | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 35328984  | Using temporary; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

From the concept, I understand that mysql will not use temp tables if columns are indexed. 
But the explain results show me that the indexes are not used for this query.
This query ran for few seconds and  got terminated after throwing up an error code :28 which mentions that system ran out of space.

Correct me if i am wrong,I understand that temp table required more space than the available space. Does this mean I need to have additional space to satisfy the issue?

Comment: try using a composite index on a,b,c,d,e. Also, your query looks like it's not aggregating, but selecting distinct.

Comment: This is the query "select a,b,c,d,sum(f) as e from table a group by a,b,c,d" It has a aggregate function. I tried using composite index. Still fails.

Comment: composite index on `a,b,c and d` not `a,b,c,d and e`, is that what you tried?

Comment: compostite index on a,b,c and d only

Comment: I have increased my heap_table_size to 2 GB and facing the same issue again.